# Spark ML - How to interact with document clustering

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

### Backgroud

We have a requirement to cluster customers' orders into certain(unknown) number of groups, according to the description data of items. Description data of each item is composed of several key words (not sentence). Here are some sample data (one line for each item).

### Sample Data

```
1. WIRE,MAGNET;SOLID;Cu;;Ø0.300mm/32AWG;;;UNCOLORED;CLASS 155;SINGLE BUILD;GRADE 1;
2. WIRE,MAGNET;SOLID;Cu;;Ø0.400mm/32AWG;;;UNCOLORED;CLASS 155;SINGLE BUILD;GRADE 1;
3. WIRE,MAGNET;SOLID;Cu;;Ø0.200mm/32AWG;;;UNCOLORED;CLASS 155;SINGLE BUILD;GRADE 1;
4. WIRE,MAGNET;SOLID;Cu;;Ø0.200mm/32AWG;;;UNCOLORED;CLASS 155;HEAVY BUILD;GRADE 2;
5. CAP;CERAMIC;;3.3nF;10%;50V;X7R;0805;;;-55to+125°C;
6. CAP;CERAMIC;;330nF;10%;50V;X7R;0805;;;-55to+125°C;
7. CAP;CERAMIC;;4.7µF;10%;16V;X7R;0805;;;-55to+125°C;
8. CAP;CERAMIC;;100pF;10%;1kV;X7R;1206;;;-55to+125°C;
9. CAP;CERAMIC;;47µF;10%;16V;X5R;1210;;;-55to+85°C;
10. CAP;CERAMIC;;22µF;10%;25V;X5R;1210;;;-55to+85°C;
11. CAP;CERAMIC;;4.7µF;10%;50V;X7R;1210;;;-55to+125°C;
12. MOSFET;N;ENH;200V;18A;0.18 Ohm;TO220;;
13. MOSFET;N;ENH;1.2kV;3A;4.5 Ohm;TO263;;
14. MOSFET;N;ENH;1.2kV;3A;4.7 Ohm;TO220;;
```

### What we've done

The data size might be of millions, so we tried it out on ***spark*** with ***mllib API*** with the following steps,

1. Do some preprocessing work (i.e. split string by punctuations and remove some stop words).
2. Compute ***tf-idf*** for each description data using ***HashingTF/IDF*** in mllib.
3. Train model with ***tf-idf*** data from step 2 using ***K-Means*** algorithm and do prediction.

This gave the initial clustering results and as expected, 1-4, 5-11, 12-14 are grouped into three clusters respectively which is promising.

### The question

If customer requires that items with different ***GRADE*** should not be grouped together. For example, data #4 should **NOT** be grouped together with data #1, #2 and #3, as #4 has ***GRADE 2*** while others having ***GRADE 1***.

```
1. WIRE,MAGNET;SOLID;Cu;;Ø0.300mm/32AWG;;;UNCOLORED;CLASS 155;SINGLE BUILD;***GRADE 1***;
2. WIRE,MAGNET;SOLID;Cu;;Ø0.400mm/32AWG;;;UNCOLORED;CLASS 155;SINGLE BUILD;***GRADE 1***;
3. WIRE,MAGNET;SOLID;Cu;;Ø0.200mm/32AWG;;;UNCOLORED;CLASS 155;SINGLE BUILD;***GRADE 1***;
4. WIRE,MAGNET;SOLID;Cu;;Ø0.200mm/32AWG;;;UNCOLORED;CLASS 155;HEAVY BUILD;***GRADE 2***;
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Split your dataset by GRADE first, then cluster each one independently.